# Timer on ListView

Tags: android, listview, timer

I am developing a fitness application and when the user chooses the movements they want to include in a workout, the movements selections are used to populate a ListView. When the user clicks the button to begin their workout, a timer appears just below the list but still on the same view.  I want the user to be able to see the workout list and the timer on the same view.  I am wondering if there is any way I can make the timer more cosmetically appealing while keeping it located on the ListView.  Just as a warning, I did a quick "rigging" of the timer because I was presenting my application the next day and it was the last thing I needed to add.  The following is the method that I used for the timer:

```
    public Runnable updateTimerThread = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {

        timeInMilliseconds = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTime;
        updatedTime = timeSwapBuff + timeInMilliseconds;

        int secs = (int) (updatedTime / 1000);
        int mins = secs / 60;
        secs = secs % 60;

        int milliseconds = (int) (updatedTime % 1000);

        timerValue.setText("" + mins + ":"
        + String.format("%02d", secs) + ":"
        + String.format("%03d", milliseconds));

        timerValue.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        customHandler.postDelayed(this, 0);
    }
};
```

I call the method here and the clock runs using callbacks:

```
startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            startButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                            // start clock
                            startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
                            customHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread, 0);
                            }
                    });
                    // labeled as End Workout button
                    pauseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            startButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            pauseButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                            congrats.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            exitApp.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                            // stop clock
                            timeSwapBuff += timeInMilliseconds;
                            customHandler.removeCallbacks(updateTimerThread);
```

All of this takes place in the same fragment.  Thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you just want to overlay the view for the timer over the listview - just use a FrameLayout (or if you're targeting 4.4+ devices only, the new overlay api)

Comment: I need it to be 4.1 and up at the very least.  Oh well, definitely food for thought. Thanks